# Is there some method of installing all commonly used packages at once on thonny (since it lacks a lot of them and I have to install them one by one)

Tags: python, package, install.packages, thonny

The title says it all, if the answer is no feel free to just reply by no. Thanks in advance! I tried using Spyder since I was told that that it comes with a lot of packages, but I found it to be huge struggle to install packages such as scikit-learn. So I switched to Thonny which has a pretty easy way of manually installing packages.

Comment: Define "commonly used packages" please?

Answer (score 0):

You can install multiple packages by using a [requirements.txt](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pip-install-requirements/) file.

1. Create your requirements.txt.
2. Open Thonny manage packages dialog.
3. Click on link under "Install from requirements file" and select your requirements.txt file.

[image]